# Adding values at the end of horizontal bar plots

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to annotate values at the end of my horizontal bar plot given by:

```
UK.groupby(['College/University']).size().sort_values(ascending=True).plot(kind='barh',figsize=(8,8),title='UK Uni')
```

If this helps:
`y=list(UK.groupby(['College/University']).size())`
returns 
`[2, 1, 5, 2, 6, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 1, 2, 12]`

Any idea? :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use matplotlib's [annotation functionality](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html) for that:

```
sizes = UK.groupby(['College/University']).size().sort_values(ascending=True)
sizes.plot(kind='barh',figsize=(8,8),title='UK Uni')

for y, x in enumerate(sizes['size']):
    plt.annotate(str(x), xy=(x, y), va='center')
```

[image]

Comment: U're the best!!Thank you